# sklearn.cross_validation raises IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was struggling with `IndexError` raised from `sklearn.cross_validation`. I solved this and seems the bug of `sklearn`.

I run the following code on ipython parallel engine:

```
kf = cross_validation.KFold(num_data, k_fold)
for k, (train, test) in enumerate(kf):
    # do something
```

and happend error

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

the place error occuring is:

```
def _iter_test_masks(self):
    """Generates boolean masks corresponding to test sets.

    By default, delegates to _iter_test_indices()
    """
    for test_index in self._iter_test_indices():
        test_mask = self._empty_mask()
        test_mask[test_index] = True # <============= Here error occurs
        yield test_mask
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

Just add `.astype('int64)`

```
def _iter_test_masks(self):
    """Generates boolean masks corresponding to test sets.

    By default, delegates to _iter_test_indices()
    """
    for test_index in self._iter_test_indices():
        test_mask = self._empty_mask()
        test_mask[test_index.astype('int64')] = True  # convert to int type
        yield test_mask
```